# random height and color for div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I've been trying to make a masonry kind of layout. I want the divs to have fixed width but random height and random colors for the divs. I am totally confused as to how to assign the divs random height and random color. I could only give same height and same color for all the divs components as shown here.

```
import React from "react";

import "./styles.scss";

export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="wrapper">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>7</div>
      <div>8</div>
      <div>9</div>
      <div>10</div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
  margin: 40px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  font: 2em Sansita, sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrapper > * {
  flex: 1 1 230px;
  border: 5px solid orange;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-meitner-h825q?file=/src/App.js:0-373)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of inline-style and add the height and color to it. For eg: You can have set of colors defined which you allow and get a random color from it.

I have done a similar thing below:

```
const colors = ["palevioletred", "red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "orange"];

const getUniqueFromRange = (min, max) => {
  return Math.floor(min + Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
};

const getRandomItem = items => {
  return items[getUniqueFromRange(0, items.length)];
};


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="wrapper">
        {Array.from({ length: 10 }).map((item, index) => (
          <div
            key={index}
            style={{
              background: getRandomItem(colors),
              height: getUniqueFromRange(100, 200)
            }}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: not exactly getting the desired result. can you check my sandbox? the last div is having different width but i want all the div to have fixed width.

Comment: also there are spaces y origin margins between the divs. how to make the margin uniform on all the divs?

Answer (score 0):

This will assign a random hex color and random height (from *minheight* to *maxheight*) to each element that is a child of a *wrapper* class element.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper > *").forEach((div)=>{
    div.style.height = Math.round((Math.random() * (maxheight - minheight)) + minheight);
    var color = Math.round(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    color = "0".repeat(6 - color.length)  + color;
    div.style.backgroundColor = "#" + color;
});
```